# 2 html files and 2 js files conflict

Tags: javascript, import, export

I have 4 files:
index.html, index.js, post.html, post.js

In index.html linked index.js

```
<script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
```

In post.html linked post.js

```
<script src="post.js" type="module"></script>
```

index.js have one export

```
export const arrayId = getId(list.data);
```

post.js have one import

```
import { arrayId } from "./index.js";
```

index.js also render list of topics to index.html.

```
function createList(data) {
      let ul = document.createElement('ul');
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        let li = document.createElement('li');
        let a = document.createElement('a');
        a.textContent = data[i].title;
        a.href = 'post.html?id=' + data[i].id;
        li.appendChild(a);
        ul.appendChild(li);
      }
      document.querySelector('#app').appendChild(ul);
    }
```

Question: When function createList run in index.js - it affects both html files and render list in index.html and in post.html. Why it happens?

I try to pass one variable from one js file to another, through import/export. But unexpectedly another function running in both html files.
If I deleting type module from post.js, all returns to normal. But without it I cant import data.